# Did the Bobs want to fire Lumbergh in Office Space?

Tags: plot-explanation, office-space

Wasn't Lumbergh the Vice President in *Office Space*?

Then how did the Bobs want to fire him? How much power did those consultants have?

Comment: @dbugger Yea but that doesn't explain why they had his profile on hand in the stack of papers "to be fired".

Comment: It's possible the Bobs kept Lumbergh on top of the "to be fired" pile as a trap. If any employee commented on it, that might show disloyalty to Lumbergh, then ... pink slip. I mean, being efficiency experts, they were probably looking for, err, efficient ways  to get through the charade and fire people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that Lumbergh was a VP, and that his job was really not on the line.  The Bobs ended up liking Peter Gibbons, presumably because he was so plainly honest about what went on at Initech.  So when Lumbergh gave Peter a thumbs down, the Bobs went to bat for Peter and started to analyze why Lumbergh didn't understand Peter.

Comment: Yea but that doesn't explain why they had his profile on hand in the stack of papers "to be fired".

Comment: Fair enough.  But thinking of that concept just makes me laugh, and that's the intent of the movie.  In the real world, it's a good presumption that the seniority of the officer that hires the consultants will determine who is at risk -- namely all less senior officers and below.  I don't think the movie explains those details.